# select different results based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have the following query:

```
select a,b,c,firstConditionKey,secondConditionkey from 
(select ..... - big query - ..... ) as main;
```

What I need is to return a single row out of the query so if `firstConditionKey` is not null, the row would be like `min(firstConditionKey)` since I don't care which row it is as long as it is a row that has a `firstConditionKey`, else, if there are no rows with `firstconditionKey`, return a row out of the ones that have a `secondConditionKey` or nothing if there are none.

```
a   b   c   firstConditionKey   secondConditionKey
x   x   x          1                    1
x   x   x          2                    2
x   x   x                               2

a   b   c   firstConditionKey   secondConditionKey
x   x   x                                
x   x   x                               2
x   x   x                               2
```

So in the first case I would return the first row.
In the second case I would return the second row.

Basically, if there is a row with `firstConditionKey`, return the first one you find, else, return the first row with a `secondConditionKey`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysql, but I guess I would create an additional field in the inside query which would have a value of 2 of first existed or 1 if only second did else 0, then bring one row with the max value of that field.

Comment: Something like `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... WHERE <first condition> UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE <second condition>) LIMIT 1` maybe?

Comment: I strongly suggest giving example data.  Create various example result from your sub-query, and then show the output that you require.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Add this, then limit 1 in the outer order by it:, case 
 when firstConditionKey is not null then 2
 when secondConditionkey is not null then 1
 else 0 end as priority,

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thanks. Filtering in order by did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row, you can use `order by` and `limit`.  So, the basic idea is:

```
select a, b, c, firstConditionKey, secondConditionkey
from (select ..... - big query - ..... ) main
order by (firstConditionKey is not null) desc,
         (secondConditionKey is not null) desc
limit 1;
```

This doesn't solve the last condition of returning no rows if both keys are `NULL`, so let's phrase this as:

```
select a, b, c, firstConditionKey, secondConditionkey
from (select ..... - big query - ..... ) main
where firstConditionKey is not null or secondConditionKey is not null
order by (firstConditionKey is not null) desc,
         (secondConditionKey is not null) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Already did something similar but this is the answer! Thanks.